# Minification and GZip won't work together

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, gzip, minify

I am using the [bundling and minification support](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/11/27/new-bundling-and-minification-support-asp-net-4-5-series.aspx) to minify my css and Javascript files in my MVC **3** project. The minification works fine but the minified files seem to pass through without compression on IIS 7.5.

Is this a known issue? If yes any workarounds?

Comment: Are you using MVC 4/ASP.NET 4.5 RC B/M - it's changed radically from Beta.

Comment: Nope. Using the beta in MVC 3.

Comment: upgrade (see my upgrade blog) and See my [Bundling and Minification tutorial][1]
  [1]: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minificationhttp://mvchtml5.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Rick. Thanks. The link doesn't work, I guess it should be http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Comment: Hey NVM, did you ever find an answer on this? It's something I've just come up against now.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Bundling and minification compressed with GZip, will work with dynamic compression enabled. According to this article it is relatively safe to enable dynamic compression without much CPU overhead:

[Is it worth it to enable dynamic compression in IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831041/is-it-worth-it-to-enable-dynamic-compression-in-iis7)